# Добавить иконку в EditText

Tags: android, view, icon

Как можно добавить иконку в поле вводе `EditText`, Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходник:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageMode"
    style="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Пароль"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - это добавить к EditText такую строчку:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon"
    ...
/>
```